# Dynamic social app credentials in socialite package in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to build a multi tenant app, where I have configured the database, the views folder, I know there must be some way out to configure the credentials of social app login for socialite. Well I tried few things to set it dynamically.

**STEP 1**

I created a class with the name of socialite in a separate folder and when the social login is called I'm implementing the following in my controller:

```
public function redirectSocialLogin()
{
    $social = new SocialiteProvider();
    $fb = $social->makeFacebookDriver();
    return $fb->redirect();
}
```

and while callback I used following:

```
public function callbackSocialLogin($media)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($media)->user();
    $data['name'] = $user->getName();
    $data['email'] = $user->getEmail();
    dd($data);
}
```

In my class I've following codes:

```
public function makeFacebookDriver()
{
    $config['client_id'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $config['client_secret'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $config['redirect'] = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXX/auth/facebook/callback';
    return  Socialite::buildProvider('\Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider', $config);
}
```

It redirects perfectly to the social page but while getting a callback I'm getting an error, It again fetches the services.php file for configuration and doesn't get any.

**STEP 2**

I made a `ServiceProvider` under the name of `SocialiteServiceProvider` and extended the core `SocialiteServiceProvider` and placed the following codes:

```
protected function createFacebookDriver()
{
    $config['client_id'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $config['client_secret'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $config['redirect'] = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXX/auth/facebook/callback';

    return $this->buildProvider(
        'Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider', $config
    );
}
```

But again it throws back error which says `driver is not setup`. Help me out in this.
Thanks.

Comment: Nitish kumar ,can  u  show inside  (new SocialiteProvider()) ,i tried lot ,i can't find  a right article to achieve dyanmic client_id ,secret_key.what is inside your SocialiteProvider().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **STEP 1**, update the callback as below mentioned & try. `$media` is actually `Request`. So when initialising `Socialite::driver($media)` you are actually passing `Request` where you have to pass `Facebook`.

```
public function callbackSocialLogin(Request $request) {
    $fbDriver = (new SocialiteProvider())->makeFacebookDriver();

    $user = $fbDriver->user();
    $data['name']  = $user->getName();
    $data['email'] = $user->getEmail();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm doing so about `$media` and your solution worked. Silly thing which I forgot to implement. Thanks a lot. Cheers.

Comment: how should configure inside  SocialiteProvider()?